# Connecting to MongoDB with SSH results in error "command hostInfo requires authentication"

Tags: mongodb, ssh, mongodb-compass

I'm new to MongoDB, and I have a MongoDB instance on an AWS server. I want to access it using Compass Interface, but I don't want to open 27017 port on the firewall, I want to connect with SSH tunnel option.

So I clicked "Fill in connection fields individually" option on Compass, and then clicked on "More Options" tab and selected SSH Tunnel : Use Identity File option

Entered server address, user and selected the PPK file as in the picture below:
[image]

When I click "Connect", Compass freezes for 1-2 seconds and a red line shown on the top as below picture saying:

> An error occurred while loading navigation: command hostInfo requires
> authentication

[image]

On MongoDB, I have a user with name "admin" and it has a password. As far as I understand, Compass successfully connected to the server over SSH, but can't connect to the database because the database password required for it.

I don't see any place on Compass to enter the DB user and password,
how can I make Compass connect to a database?

Comment: You Identity file also requires authentication. I guess that can be a reason.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, but sorry I think I didn't understand what you mean exactly